# Verifying user input in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make a program and I need to verify if the user input should be the first 2 segments of an ip (something like 00.000 or 000.000 etc, where 0 could be any digit) but the program says that the input is correct even if it is 213.1532.

```
if ($user input =~ m/(\d){3}.(\d){3}|(\d){2}.(\d){2}|(\d).(\d)|(\d){3}.(\d){2}|(\d){3}.(\d)|(\d){2}.(\d){3}|(\d).(\d){3}|(\d){2}.(\d)|(\d).(\d){2}/) {
    print "it works"
}
```

Comment: The dot is a special character in regex for any character you have to escape it with backslash.

Comment: @Jens is correct. There's a site at Perlmonks which shows you the proper Regex: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1148750

Comment: I think you also need to anchor the regex to the beginning of the string and to the end of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$user input` is a syntax error. Did you mean `$user_input`?

`.` is a special character in regexes, matching any character (except `"\n"` (unless you use `/s`)). It needs to be escaped as `\.` to match literally.

Your regex is not anchored, so it will match any substring of the input.

There's no need to put parens around `\d`.

The whole thing can be simplified a lot:

```
if ($user_input =~ /\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\z/a) {
    print "it works\n";
}
```

- `\A` matches the beginning of the string.
- `\d` matches a digit; the `/a` flag ensures it only matches ASCII digits (`0-9`).
- `{1,3}` means "between 1 and 3 of the previous thing".
- `\.` matches a literal dot.
- `\z` matches the end of the string.

(If `$user_input` is the result of a [`readline`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/readline) operation, don't forget to [`chomp`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/chomp) it beforehand.)

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I meant user_input.

Comment: @Nevg If this answer solved your problem, consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).